# ROS Answers SE migration: Is ROS for me?

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a hobby robot from a old powered wheelchair. For the brains I have built a mini PC (intel core i3). For the motor controllers I am using two 25amp pololu simple motor controllers that can controlled over USB. I have a USB video camera that I'll use as well as a high power wifi radio.  I consider myself to be a beginner at the software side of robotics. I have programmed some with the arduino compiler and visual basic. For right now I would like to be able to control the robot remotely and see what it sees. Just something to play around with until I can program more complex actions. **My question is, is ros the best route for me to start from scratch with?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49348/is-ros-for-me?/) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is almost certainly a *good* choice. Many hobbyists use it effectively.

Whether it's your *best* option is for you to decide. Most of us here use it heavily and like it, so our responses will tend to favor ROS.

You should understand that ROS is complex. It provides many useful features, but learning it will take a while.

As @dornhege said: work through the [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials). They will give you a clear understanding of the basics. If you like what you see, you'll be well on your way. If you don't, you'll know to look elsewhere.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2